# Cassandra keeping incremental backups AND commitlog archive?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, database-backups, opscenter

I am currently refining a cassandra backup solution.

So i am stumbling upon the point if i should save incremental_backups AND commitlog_archive.

If i understand correctly, restoring from either

Snapshot + Incremental Backups + Commitlog (only these after the last flush)

OR

Snapshot + Commitlog from archive

should end in the same set of data, right?
Or is the latter option much slower because of replaying takes longer than just checking the sstables integrity?

Should i keep both?

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer incremental backups over commit logs.

Incremental backups result in links to immutable sstables which can then be replayed back to a live Cassandra cluster using sstableloader. When incremental backups are enabled (disabled by default), Cassandra hard-links each flushed SSTable to a backups directory under the keyspace data directory. The disadvantage of incremental backups is that it is all or nothing, it is not possible to select a subset of column families for incremental backup. As I mentioned before, the ability to restore to a live Cassandra cluster to a different column family makes incremental backups superior. And you also have to manage incremental backup space because there is no utility to clean up incremental backups over time or even do a rebase.

The advantage of commit logs is that it provides a point in time restore capability. To restore from commit logs, you have to go to the latest incremental backup or the latest snaphshot (in your former case), stop the database, clear the existing commit logs, copy the commit logs till the latest incremental backup or snapshot, run the rollforward utility to bring the database to the exact point in time that you require.

However, if you use only commit logs, your database downtime is going to be higher as you have more commit logs to process while the database is down. So, I would use the incremental backup approach and then use commit logs.

Lastly, better to use a professional tool out here rather than hacking this on your own - from experience with multiple customers, both the first and second approaches are fraught with potential for error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your restore requirements. If you want to restore to particular time then you will need **snapshot, incremental and commit logs**.

why Commit logs ?

- If you take snapshot at 11:00 am today. And you want to restore for 11:30 am today. Now If you only use **incremental backups** which cover 11:30 am.
  Then there is possibility you will have some extra/missing data. 
  If some one deletes one row at 11:31 am and you have **SSTables** in incremental backups which has been flushed at 11:32 am so during restore you will find above row as a **tombstone** which is wrong if you consider the restore time.

**So for particular time restore you need to process commit logs along with full snapshot and incremental backups.**